# MySQL Connection Failed

Tags: php, mysql

I want to build a website on Ubuntu 14.
I have apache, PHP and Mysql installed on it.

I'm using PHP to connect to Mysql but got the error information as follows:

```
Connection Failed: SQLSTATE[28000][1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Can you show the script you're using? The error is related to login, do you know the password for root user of your mysql? Check that the credentials are fine by using mysql on command line.

Comment: Look like wrong password issue, have you try login from terminal? `mysql -u root -p`

Comment: Show some `php` code you are using for connection.

Answer (score 0):

Probabbly Wrong Password issue or you didn't set the password for root yet. Try login from terminal using `mysql -u root -p` and it will asking your current root password.

If you are running a website, do not using root access for your website user access. Create an account with access to specified database.